# Is using the term avatar haram when it’s inspired by Hinduism?

Tags: sin, history

Assalamualaikum. Is using the term avatar in game, school and social media is Haram when it’s inspired by Hinduism? It’s hard to avoid the term in this era. I ask a sheikh about it and he said it’s permissible but my was was is so bad that I need an explanation before I believed i. Please answer this and thank you so much!